Issue with URP transparent Material
I recently started a new project in Unity, using its Universal Render Pipeline (URP).
I also just made a jar asset for said game in Blender which I imported into my project.
The next thing I did is creating a new material which I gave the albedo texture of my model.
This is what it looked like:

If you realized that the glass isn't transparent, you're correct. I did solve that issue though, by just setting the "Surface type" to "Transparent". But then it looked like this:

This is not the end though. I removed the albedo texture, which is also the alpha texture, and it still looked like:

As you can see, the bottom part of the jar is still rendered above the "Lid".
For clearance, yes, the "color" field next to the texture also has the alpha value to the max, which should result in a complete opaque look. And the lid part of the texture is fully opaque.
Furthermore, I did recalculate the normals in Blender and reimported the mesh, which did not solve my issue.
As mentioned in the title, and the first part of the post, I am using Unity's URP, and I'm on version 2022.3.27f1
If my PC stats somehow may be the issue here they are:
- CPU: AMD RYZEN 7 7800X3D
- GPU: AMD RADEON RX 7900 XTX
- RAM: 64GB
- OS: Windows
Thanks in advance for your help.

there should be 2 materials, the lid, the body, the body needs to be transparent, the lid, maybe not.. depending on exactly what you need

@BugFinder Woah, thanks! I actually didn't need 2 materials, I just needed to seperate the body mesh from the lid mesh in blender. Now it works! Thanks!

either way works :D but there should have been 2 different materials one body one lid, but now you can do more magic having the lid separate :D so yay you

You should post also a screenshot of the shader you're using. My guess is that you're drawing this either additevely or multiplicatively.
